# Where are you going on holiday, Julian?

Tags: pattern, geography, knowledge

Mary asks: "Where are you going on holiday this year, Julian?"

Julian says: "What do you mean - this year? You know that I don't go every year.
I did not go at all in 2007.  In Summer 2008 I went to Greenland, in July 2009
to India, and in July 2010 I went to Chile.
I did not go in 2011 and also not in 2013 and also not in 2014.
In November 2012 I went to Australia, and in March 2016 I will go to Sulawesi."

Mary insists: "And what about your holidays in 2015?"

To which Julian answers: "???? ???? ?????? ?????? ?????? ?? ?????? ?????????"

**Question:
What is Julian's holiday destination in 2015?**

Comment: I believe the final question is in the wrong tense. He would have already travelled this year.

Comment: The tense is fine. Mary knows nothing about Julian's holiday this year. Hence she asks where he will spend it (not knowing that he has already returned).

Comment: Mary knows nothing of it, but the bolded question is not posed from Mary's point of view. Mary's question is the correct tense, but your question to us is not. Phrasing it as "What is the answer to Mary's question?" would not require a tense to apply to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of those dates and locations refer to

> total solar eclipse viewings.

As I stated in my comment, the tense of the question is wrong as the travel for 2015 would have already taken place on March 20th.

The destination for the 2015 trip is

> [the Faroe Islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faroe_Islands).

Answer (score 1):

India , March 20th. The link is Total Solar Eclipse

Comment: I think you've found the connection, [but I'm pretty sure India isn't the right destination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_solar_eclipses_in_the_21st_century)